# Repeating the code in Python

Tags: python, loops

I have build a code in Python that is for booking seats in a theatre. The code works fine apart from I need to be able to repeat the code in a loop, so once some seats are booked you are given the option to book more seats.

This is the code:

```
NumSeat = input ("Please enter the number of seats you desire: ")
print (" ")
import re

if re.match("[0-9]", NumSeat):
    if int(NumSeat) > 6:
        print ("You may only book a maximum of 6 seats")
    else:
        if int(NumSeat) < 1:
            print ("You must book at least 1 seat")
        else:
            SeatRow = input ("Please enter the row you want to sit in: ")

            if len(SeatRow) > 1:
                print ("Invalid row")
            else:
                if SeatRow.count ("A") or SeatRow.count ("a") == 1:
                    print ("The seats avaiable in row", SeatRow, "for", int(NumSeat), "people are", RowA[0],"-", RowA[int(NumSeat)-1])
                    RowA = RowA[int(NumSeat):]
                else:
                    if SeatRow.count ("B") or SeatRow.count ("b") == 1:
                        print ("The seats avaiable in row", SeatRow, "for", int(NumSeat), "people are", RowB[0],"-", RowB[int(NumSeat)-1])
                        RowB = RowB[int(NumSeat):]
                    else:
                        if SeatRow.count ("C") or SeatRow.count ("c") == 1:
                            print ("The seats avaiable in row", SeatRow, "for", int(NumSeat), "people are", RowC[0],"-", RowC[int(NumSeat)-1])
                            RowC = RowC[int(NumSeat):]
                        else:
                            if SeatRow.count ("D") or SeatRow.count ("d") == 1:
                                print ("The seats avaiable in row", SeatRow, "for", int(NumSeat), "people are", RowD[0],"-", RowD[int(NumSeat)-1])
                                RowD = RowD[int(NumSeat):]
                            else:
                                if SeatRow.count ("E") or SeatRow.count ("e") == 1:
                                    print ("The seats avaiable in row", SeatRow, "for", int(NumSeat), "people are", RowE[0],"-", RowE[int(NumSeat)-1])
                                    RowE = RowE[int(NumSeat):]
                                else:
                                    print("Invalid row")
else:
    print ("You must input a number")
```

It would be great if you had any suggestions

Comment: Wow, this is one of the ugliest snippets of code I have ever seen.  You should really think about the Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY) principle of software design.  I am sorry to give you such a negative feedback, you may of course disagree, but helping you to entangle yourself in even more repetitions... would be prejudicial to yourself.  You should look for help in re-designing this, not for help in getting it to somehow work.

Comment: I did work before, but I did tidy it up after I posted it

Answer (score 0):

But your question is for avoiding repetition, you could create a dictionary. You could remove the if/else or if elif altogether by using a dictionary where the row is the key, and adding the arrays of seats inside. You may need to force the row to be the first element `a1` for example, if not some parsing will be required. For example you could do:

```
import re

#initialize the rows, 
valid_rows = [ 'a','b','c','d']
row_size = 10  # 10 seats per row

rows = dict(zip(valid_rows, [range(row_size)]*len(valid_rows))) # as suggested by Burhan in comments

# a forever loop booking seats (if no errors happen)
while(True):
    num_seat = int(raw_input ("Please enter the number of seats you desire: "))
    if re.match("[0-9]", str(num_seat)):
        if num_seat > 6:
            print ("You may only book a maximum of 6 seats")
        elif num_seat < 1:
            print ("You must book at least 1 seat")
        else:
            seat_row = raw_input("Please enter the row you want to sit in: ")

            if seat_row in valid_rows:
                if len(rows[seat_row]) < num_seat:
                    print "Not space in that row"
                else:
                    print ("The seats avaiable in row", seat_row, "for", 
                        num_seat, "people are", rows[seat_row][0],"-", rows[seat_row][num_seat-1])
                    rows[seat_row] = rows[seat_row][num_seat:]
            else:
                print("Invalid row")
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, but what I'm looking for is how I could integrate a "for" or "while" (or something else) statement that would allow me to repeat my code.

Comment: You dont need a for or while for checking the columns/rows

Comment: `rows = dict(zip(valid_rows, [row_size]*len(valid_rows)))`